# Enable Internet Connection Sharing programmatically

Tags: networking, windows-7, routes, nat

I can do it manually by right-clicking on a network connection, opening the Sharing tab, clicking on the "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection" check box, and selecting a "Home networking connection".

While poking around this problem I have found multiple sets of COM interfaces:

1) [Internet Connection Sharing and Internet Connection Firewall Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with INetSharingManager

Its documentation says:

> Internet Connection Firewall may be altered or unavailable in
>   subsequent versions. Instead, use the Windows Firewall API.

Moreover, the [INetSharingConfiguration.EnableSharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method does not look like it corresponds the procedure described above because its arguments don't include the "Home networking connection".

2) [Windows Firewall for Windows XP with SP2 Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Its documentation references us further:

> For Windows Vista and later, use of the Windows Firewall with Advanced
>   Security API is recommended.

3) [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are only the following interfaces: `INetFwPolicy2, INetFwProduct, INetFwProducts, INetFwRule, INetFwRule2, INetFwRule3, INetFwRules, INetFwServiceRestriction`. Does not look very promising.

Now I'm lost. Which API should I use on Windows 7?

Comment: Would you be able to share a Github gist of the script that you finally used?

Comment: @MarkKCowan: I finally wrote this: https://github.com/utapyngo/icsmanager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utapyngo

Which is your final choice?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-tw/windowssdk/thread/19f7581d-29c7-4109-85d4-6a79ee4d1577

"I was able to find the solution. You have to enable the public interface on the adapter you are connecting to and enable sharing on the private interface for the adapter you want to be able to use for the network."

Comment: The answer field is for answers not for questions.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see that `INetSharingConfiguration.EnableSharing` is the right method because `INetSharingConfiguration` corresponds to a single connection. But please format your answer appropriately. You may use the "Blockquote" button for quoting.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore on Win 10 Anniversary Update - access violation (a null pointer is dereferenced inside hnetcfg.dll when an app calls DisableSharing or EnableSharing)

Answer (score 3):

The access violation only occurs on Win 10 Anniversary Update if the call is made by a 32bit program on a 64bit OS. It works with 32 bit program on 32bit OS or 64bit program on 64bit OS

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this hint, works perfectly fine now once I started using the API from a 64-bit app.