# ICS Win 7 Hnetcfg, INetSharingConfiguration set a specific connection to one of the devices available

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I managed to write a code to use the Sharing Enabled method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
But it sets the sharing to non specific connection.
Is there a way to pass an argument or another function that will set the ICS enabled connection to share with with a connection of my choice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're searching `INetSharingConfiguration.EnableSharing` function.
Youre not the unique with the ICS problems in Win7 hehe. [Read this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294820/enable-internet-connection-sharing-programmatically)

Im not sure if [This documentation at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is usefull. I see minimum client XP, but don't see anything about further compatibility on Vista/7.

[This other question at superusers maybe can help you.](https://superuser.com/questions/470319/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line). A guy says he made a cool app for that.

if you need a simple way to sharing with ICS under Win7 from cmd,[you can download a POWERFULL ICS manager (cmd or Gui, .net)](https://superuser.com/questions/470319/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line) - See comment #3.