# How to set "Home networking connection" on network interface? C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I've created a VPN Connection program that is capable of sharing VPN connection through ICS (Internet Connection Sharing), for doing this I've used [VirtualRouter](https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) API.

Anyways, VirtualRouter works fine with sharing OpenVPN connection, but when it comes to VPN (PPTP, L2TP etc..) it throws this exception:

```
The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
```

after showing this error, VirtualRouter is already started but it wont set `Home networking connection` on my VPN network interface which I should set it manually to make it work!

Is there any way to set the `Home networking connection` by code? (it doesn't matter if its PowerShell, CMD, or C#..)

[image]

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294820/enable-internet-connection-sharing-programmatically) looks very similar

Comment: Yes but no reliable answer